# Помогите со скриптом greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, button, greasemonkey

Есть кнопка и её функция:

```
/*----- Button Click -----*/
function minButtonC()
{
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('span.icon-name2'); // Ищем все ссылки с классом "icon-name2"
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(e){ // Проходим все найденные ссылки
    e.click(); // Кликаем!
  });
}
```

Суть такова. Нужно что-бы скрипт искал все ссылки с классом "icon-name2" (что уже сделано) и нажимал первые 10 ссылок, потом ждал 15 секунд и так до тех пор, пока не закончатся ссылки. (например: 1, 2, 3, 10 - ожидание 15 секунд и дальше 10, 11, 12, 20 - ожидание 15 секунд...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var chunks = [];

function clickLinks() {
    var chunk = chunks.pop();
    if(chunk) {
        chunk.forEach(function(e) { e.click(); });
        setTimeout(clickLinks, 15000);
    }
}

var chunkSize = 10;
for (i=0, x=0; i < links.length; i+=chunkSize, x+) {
    var chunk = a.slice(i,i+chunk);
    chunks.push(chunk);
}

clickLinks();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я так понимаю в var chunk = chunks.pop(); должна размещатся сама ссылка?

Comment: Для спасибо рядом с ответом есть специальная зелёная галочка ;) В chunk будут или 10 ссылок или undefined, если массив chunks пуст..